# Struggling to get Solve to accept assumptions

Tags: equation-solving, assumptions

I can't get `Solve` to solve the following two equations under the appropriate assumptions.

When I enter

```
fs = I Cos[(s + t)/2] Sin[beta/2] - 1/2 Cos[beta/2] Sin[(s - t)/2]
ft = I Cos[(s + t)/2] Sin[beta/2] + 1/2 Cos[beta/2] Sin[(s - t)/2]
Solve[
  {fs == 0, ft == 0}, {s, t}, 
  Assumptions -> 
    Element[beta, Reals] && (beta > 0) && (beta < Pi/2) && 
      (s >= 0) && (s <= 2*Pi) && (t >= 0) && (t <= 2*Pi)
]
```

I get the following result:

```
{{s -> ConditionalExpression[π/2, Cos[beta/2] > 0 || Cos[beta/2] < 0], 
  t -> ConditionalExpression[π/2, Cos[beta/2] > 0 || Cos[beta/2] < 0]}, 
  {s -> ConditionalExpression[(3 π)/2, Cos[beta/2] > 0 || Cos[beta/2] < 0], 
  t -> ConditionalExpression[(3 π)/2, Cos[beta/2] > 0 || Cos[beta/2] < 0]}}
```

But I have told it that beta is real, that beta > 0 and beta < Pi/2. So why is it still putting a `ConditionalExpression` on the value of `Cos[beta]` being positive or negative?

Comment: Note that there is no need to add an assumption that a variable is real if you also add an inequality assumption on it: its participation in an inequality automatically implies that it is real.

Comment: `Solve` eliminates assumptions from the conditions that are unnecessary but retains those that are necessary. It's not clear to me that in every use-case, one would want the necessary condition eliminated. When they can be, I use `Simplify` as @MarcoB shows below. (Another way to look at is that there is a difference between hypothesis `Implies[A, B]` and constraints `A && B`. Hypotheses may be ignored if `B` can be solved, though that is not what Mma usually does.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your definitions of `fs` and `ft`, try this:

```
assumptions = {0 < beta < Pi/2, 0 <= s <= 2Pi, 0 <= t <= 2Pi};
Assuming[assumptions, Simplify@ Solve[{fs == 0, ft == 0}, {s, t}]]

(* Out: {{s -> π/2, t -> π/2}, {s -> (3 π)/2, t -> (3 π)/2}} *)
```

This will simplify the conditions away using the same assumptions you used for `Solve`. Note that this takes advantage of the fact that `Solve` now takes assumptions, a recent change in the language, but of course you are aware of that, since you were using it in your original code.

Comment: All right, thanks. But this is still disappointing though. Firstly, in your solution, Mathematica first has to solve the most general equation, and then only afterwards apply the constraints. It would be much more efficient, and indispensable for harder problems, to first apply the constraints and then solve the equation under those constraints. Secondly, it means Mathematica has a bug, since my code should have worked too.

Comment: @BruceBartlett - Using `Assuming`, the assumptions are used by any enclosed function that uses the option `Assumptions`. Consequently, this solution does exactly what your solution did for `Solve`. In addition, `Assuming` makes the assumptions available to the enclosed `Simplify` without having to repeat them. `Solve` does not automatically `Simplify`.

Comment: All right, that's good news, thank you. So Mathematica evaluates from outside-in?

Comment: @BruceBartlett Not quite. I would guess that `Assuming` temporarily changes the value of the `$Assumptions` global variable to whatever assumptions you give it. Code executing within `Assuming` will then pick up on those "temporary" global assumptions. Those are removed once execution is done. In other words, `Assuming` behaves more or less as the following: `Block[{$Assumptions = assumptions}, Simplify@Solve[{fs == 0, ft == 0}, {s, t}]]`.